# How do I batch-rename filenames in windows 7, so that they have numerical order at the end of them?

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have an archive of php files on my computer, and I want to mass rename them. Here's the problem. Here's a sample of the files (I have about 420,000 of these).

```
viewtopic.php_id=4
viewtopic.php_id=5
viewtopic.php_id=6
```

I want ALL these files in .php. Now, I know to rename the file extensions you go to cmd and cd to the file, then go `"ren *.* *.php"`.

However, I can't do this, because ALL files are named `VIEWTOPIC`. I would love to have it so it renames all files to
 `viewtopic1, viewtopic2, viewtopic3`, or hell even `1,2,3,4,5,6,7, etc`, .php. THEN after that, I can batch rename the files thru cmd.

Comment: Not really on-topic for SO, but on Windows I have used acdsee in the past to mass-rename (image...) files. However, depending on the source of the information, reading them again and parsing the information & storing it in a database might be a better option...

Comment: how about just adding another `.php`, so you get `viewtopic.php_id=4.php`? `ren "*.php*" "*.php*.php"`

Comment: @Stephan , that's exactly what I needed. I feel so dumb for not thinking of that. Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own so far? please share your code... if not, a good starting point is to use `for` loop to iterate over all the `viewtopic.php_id=*` files, then use `~x` modifier of `for` loop to get file extension `.php_id=*`; then you can do string manipulation to extract the numeric part, and finally append it to the original file name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to rename viewtopic.php_id=`x` to viewtopic`x`.php.

```
:: Simple Batch Script

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Assuming all files exist in same directory tree.  
:: Note - this will take a while.  Probably 30 minutes or more ( just a guess )

:: Also - I am not going to add a check to see if they are php_id files.
:: If you have other file types in this subdirectory,
:: it  will effect them too, and the results will be unpredictable. 
:: Could add a check for it, but easier move *.php_id* into their own subdirectory

for /r %%i in ( * ) do (
    :: set extension to everything after the period
    set "extension=%%~nxi"

    :: remove everything that is not the number
    set "num=!extension:php_id^==!"

    :: rename the original file the file name (%%~ni) + the number + ".php"
    rename %%i %%~ni!num!.php
 )

endlocal
@echo on
```

Comment: no need to check filetypes or risk unpredictable results, just choose your filemask correct: `for /r %%i in ( *.php_id*.php ) do (`..